# Помогите найти ошибку . С++ . Строки

Tags: c++, строки, visual-c++, ввод

Задание: С клавиатуры вводится строка символов состоящая из нескольких слов, необходимо вычислить и вывести на экран количество символов каждой лексемы (слова). В качестве разделителя используется одиночный пробел.

Код:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <conio.h>
#include <string>
#include <cstring>

using namespace std;


int main()
{
    setlocale(LC_ALL, "rus");
    cout << "Введите строку: ";
    char str[100]; //
    cin.getline(str, 100);
    int size = strlen(str); // Размер массива str

    for (int i = 0; i < size; i++)
    {
        if (str[i] == ' ')
        { // Поиск пробелов 
            cout << endl;
        }
        else
        {
            cout << str;
        }
    }

}
```

Answer (score 1):

```
cin >> str;
```

читает *только одно слово* (см. учебник или справочник по С++).

Читать строку полностью можно с помощью функции [`getline`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/basic_istream/getline):

```
cin.getline(str,100);
```

Comment: 0_0 я сам об этом тока узнал, хотя c++ моя основа :)

Comment: мдааа как же смешно!

Comment: спасибо , но программа стала выводить введенные слова несколько раз  . Все равно ничего не считает

Answer (score 0):

Программа ничего не считает, потому что вы не ввели счётчик. Для того, чтобы она считала, надо где-то хранить данные о количестве найденных слов. Но необходимой переменной я так и не увидел, увы. Кроме того, вы каждый раз печатаете строку заново, по тому она и будет выводить вам уже найденные слова. Для того, чтобы такого не было, нам надо запоминать индекс, на котором было встречено предыдущее слово и выводить все символы начиная с него и до текущего пробела. И кстати последнее слово оно вам тоже считать не будет, потому что по умолчанию пробел в конце не добавляется. В общем исправленная версия программы должна будет выглядеть как-то так:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <conio.h>
#include <string>
#include <cstring>

using namespace std;


int main()
{
    setlocale(LC_ALL, "rus");
    cout << "Ââåäèòå ñòðîêó: ";
    char str[100]; //
    cin.getline(str, 100);
    int size = strlen(str); // Ðàçìåð ìàññèâà str
    int k = 0, m = 0;


    for (int i = 0; i < size; i++)
    {
        if (str[i] == ' ' || i+1 == size)
        { // Ïîèñê ïðîáåëîâ 

            for(int j = m; j <= i; j++ )
            {
                cout << str[j];
            }

            cout << endl;
            k++;
            m = i+1;
        }
    }

    cout << k << endl;

}
```

При входных данных например: word1 word2 word3
выходные данные будут : word1 word2 word3 3

Answer (score 0):

Для решения Ваше задачи воспользуйтесь  std::istringstream.

При работе  этим потоков Вы можете разбить строку на лексемы в std::string, а у него уже есть метод size

Вот пример : Вместо ввода, я захардкодил строку....

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <sstream>


int main() {

    std::string str("a bb ccc dddd");

    std::istringstream ist(str);
    std::string tmp_str;

    while (ist >> tmp_str) {
        std::cout << "word [ " << tmp_str << " ], size : " << tmp_str.size() << std::endl;
    }

    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
#include <iostream>
#include <conio.h>
#include <string>
#include <cstring>

using namespace std;

int main() {
    setlocale(LC_ALL, "rus");
    cout << "Введите строку: ";
    char str[100]; //
    cin.getline(str, 100);
    strcat(str, " ");
    char last = ' ';
    int lsize = 0;

    for (char* c = str; *c; ++c) {
        if (*c == ' ') {
            if (last != ' ') {
                cout << " : lexem size = " << lsize << endl;
                last = ' ';
                }
            }
        else {
            if (last == ' ') {
                lsize = 1;
                last = *c;
                }
            else lsize++;

            cout << *c;
            }
        }
    }
```